# How do you style XML documents being displayed on a web page using either Javascript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, jsp

I have developed a small portal that will extract an XML document from a DB table and display it to the user.

I have pretty printed the XML document using vkbeatify.js, however I would also now like to style the XML document to represent the XML tags as a different colour from the XML Values.

How can this be achieved?

The XML documents can be of varying structures.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I had a look and couldnt find an appropriate solution on here.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

At the moment the XML documents are displayed in a textarea, however I am open to changing this to something more suitable if it will allow for the XML document to be formatted and coloured appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your XML schemas are known, you can use XSLT to transform the XML into HTML.

[MSDN XSLT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765388(v=vs.85).aspx)

This won't be a good solution if you need to display the XML structure itself to the user, but you will be able to color code everything in whatever way you want using html/css.

---

Edit:

Because you are rending the "beautified" xml in a textarea, it is just text. You cannot target the individual nodes as you could elements on a page. Even if you were able to add a class to a node, it would result in the class name being rendered in textarea. Similar to this: `<thing style="background-color:blue;">` instead of it rendering  as blue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, due to the nature of the XML messages that are being extracted form the table and the varying structures, it is not feasible to create XML schemas for all of the different document types

Comment: are you piping the result into a div or a textarea?

Comment: Yes, the result is sent to a textarea

Answer (score 0):

[prismjs](http://prismjs.com/index.html) works well for syntax highlighting XML markup.

> How can this be achieved?

There are several ways this can be achieved. Here's a couple of approaches you could consider:

---

#### Example 1

***Method: Fetching the XML file using the [File Highlight](http://prismjs.com/plugins/file-highlight/) plugin:***

Getting the necessary Prism Javascript and CSS:

1. Visit the [downloads](http://prismjs.com/download.html) page.
2. Select *minified version*.
3. Select *Markup* from the *Languages* section.
4. Choose a *Theme*.
5. Select *File Highlight* from the *Plugins* section - (Include the *Line Numbers* plugin too if required).
6. Download *JavaScript* and *CSS* file.

***HTML***

Link the generated files *(from step six above)* to the `.html` page you intend to use to present the `.xml` as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my/path/to/prism.css" />
```

```
<script src="my/path/to/prism.js"></script>
```

Then link to the external `.xml` to the `.html` using the `<pre>` tag and `data-src` attribute as follows:

```
<pre data-src="my/path/to/foobar.xml"></pre>
```

Edit your `.css` as required to display the syntax highlighted `.xml` to the user.

---

#### Example 2

If example one above is an issue due to the XMLHttpRequest file fetching nature of the *File Highlight* plugin. An alternative approach, although more complex is to:

***Method: Inline escaped XML to the .html page***

1. Steps 1-6 in example one are required here too, however, there's no need to include the *File Highlight* plugin.
2. Again, the generated files (from step six above) will need to be linked to the .html you intend to use to present the .xml.

The following shows the html syntax necessary for displaying the escaped XML including line numbers:

```
<pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-xml">
    &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
    &lt;root&gt;
        ...
        ...
    &lt;/root&gt;
</code></pre>
```

I've successfully used example two in the past and utilized [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) to auto read the xml, escape it, and write a `.html` for displaying to the user. But yeah, there's a myriad of ways this can be automated.

Hope this helps!